# Problem with size of the imported PDF template with FPDI+TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, pdftk, fpdi

I am stuck in a very complex situation.
I am working on a PHP Web apps for Greeting card.

For this, I am using some Linux tools and TCPDF and FPDI.
Let me tell you how it all works:

there is 4 page greeting card template PDF file. this is custom size 5x7 inches 300dpi PDF file.
I have added custom size in TCPDF as well

```
case 'STANDARD_CARD'       : {$pf = array(1500.00,2100.00);break;}
```

what i do is, i use:

```
pdftk templateX.pdf burst output  page_%2d.pdf
```

to separate each page of temple.

now I use :

```
$pdf = new FPDI($cardDetails['ORIENTATION'],"mm",$cardDetails['SIZE']);      


  //set source file for 
    $pdf->setSourceFile($pdfFile);
    $templateIndex = $pdf->importPage(1);
    $pdf->AddPage($cardDetails['ORIENTATION'],$cardDetails['SIZE']);
    $pdf->useTemplate($templateIndex,0,0);
```

other things like, writing message printing images. and at the end save the file using:

```
$pdf->output("file_name.pdf","F");
```

original PDF file (1st page only): (5x7 inches)
[Original pdf file](http://www.mediafire.com/?bdinz9tqfemj0ft)
Modified PDF and some PDF operations : (29x20 inches)
[modified PDF](http://www.mediafire.com/?y5dy4r8l3ifddak)

now the output I am getting is not 5x7 pdf it is a 29 x 20 inches file and that destroying my calculation and PDF as well.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong...

Comment: What is the contents of `$cardDetails`?

Comment: $cardDetails contain card size and orientation
`code`
$cardDetails['ORIENTATION'] = 'L';
$cardDetails['SIZE'] = 'STANDARD_CARD';
`code`

size of STANDARD_CARD is Defiled in TCPDF class as 
`code` 
case 'STANDARD_CARD'       : {$pf = array(360.00,504.00);break;}
`code`

well, I have  my problem solved (to some extent, not 100%)

I wanted to set the size of pdf to size of PDF imported, say imported pdf is 5.27 X 7.1. then set the size accordingly. but, no luck in  that, just some workable solution, not 100%, but, seems to be working for me...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Hi Ravish,**

I encountered also this issue. Actually my scenario is this. I have an original file which is a **Legal size (8.5mm x 14mmmm)**. When I an displaying it using the FPDI output as you did, it only display a **letter size(8.5mm x 11mm)**. So the result is: **CROPPED** PDF file.

I made several googling and found several answers too from different posts. Here is the most relevant solution that I found.

First is this piece of function code below: **useTemplate**

```
$this->useTemplate($templateIndex, null, null, 0, 0, true);
```

Normally, some developers set this as TRUE for the last argument. Yes, it is correct if you dont set the width and lenght. However, I would like to emphasize that the **4th and 5th argument specifies the width and length** of an imported PDF. So, if you will adopt or get the actual size of the imported document, set the last argument to **FALSE** as this will tell that it will take the actual or specific size you set.

Please take this sample codes I did:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf -> setSourceFile('birform2316.pdf');
$tplIdx = $pdf -> importPage(1);
$size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tplIdx);
$pdf -> AddPage();
$pdf ->useTemplate($tplIdx, null, null, $size['w'], 310, FALSE);
$pdf -> SetFont('Arial');
$pdf -> SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
$pdf -> SetXY(18, 174);
$pdf -> Write(0, $employer_address);
$pdf -> Output('myOwn.pdf', 'D');
```

With this code, I have produced a new PDF **WITHOUT CROPPING** the imported file that I set. Meaning, all details of the template(*the original file*) has been displayed.

Please take note also that I observed something while setting the size of my PDF:

First, my file has an original width of 215.6mm and its length is 350.9mm. Now when I set the size of my PDF using the functions **getTemplateSize** and **useTemplate** such as:

```
$size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tplIdx);
$pdf ->useTemplate($tplIdx, null, null, $size['w'], $size['h'],FALSE);
```

or simply:

```
$pdf ->useTemplate($tplIdx, null, null, 215.6, 350.9,FALSE);
```

The result is, my new PDF file is **CROPPED** at the bottom and I dont know why.

With this observation, I made several tests to find out the reason. And the result that came up is, there is a **limit of length** in generating a PDF file using FPDI. As you can see in my code above, I did not use the actual length of my file. Instead of using 350.9mm which can be derived from `$size[h']`, I did not use it as it will give a cropped file. I just passed a numeric value near to it and the actual width to produce the desired result.

```
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, null, null, $size['w'], 310, false);
```

By the way, 310 mm (length) is the largest numeric value I have used to produce a new PDF file which is **NOT CROPPED**.

I hope I have given some inputs to all developers using FPDI which encounters the problem of CROPPED PDF results.

Thanks to all...

**Levi Palmer**

Comment: The reason why the pages are cropped is that no entry in FPDIs/FPDFs `PageSizes` array is created as long as neither the page's orientation nor its size changes (see [source code](https://github.com/hanneskod/fpdi/blob/c4fa110b8a8a6940616ec1a1ef323eafd8601664/src/FPDI.php#L137)). Since the `$size` array contains float values, it works to just manually pass an integer for width or height to `useTemplate()` , because the difference between the float and the int is recognised as a changed page size and hence an entry is added to `PageSizes`.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of

```
$pdf->useTemplate($templateIndex,0,0);
```

use

```
$this->useTemplate($templateIndex, null, null, 0, 0, true);
```

The last argument `$adjustPageSize` is set to 'false' by default.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was having the same problem. where you have nulls, I had 0s. replacing them with nulls did the trick!

Comment: newer versions will complain if you use zeros for any of the params, so use all nulls, `$this->useTemplate($templateIndex, null, null, null, null, true);`

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem. My pdf was cropped from right, and from the bottom FDPI was adding space. 
I found that my pdf had width=215 and height=279, while FPDI was exporting every time 210x297.

`useTemplate` function can scale your pdf to certain size, but output will still remain 210x297. 
So I left useTemplate with default values and "adjustPageSize"=true:

```
$pdf->useTemplate($templateId, 0, 0, 0, 0, true);
```

What is need to be changed is output dimensions, in order to match original size:

```
$templateSize = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);
$pdf->AddPage('', [$templateSize['w'], $templateSize['h']]);
```

If you are going to upload landscape oriented pdfs, you must set orientation:

```
$templateSize = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);
$orientation = $templateSize['w'] > $templateSize['h'] ? 'L' : 'P';
$pdf->AddPage($orientation, [$templateSize['w'], $templateSize['h']]);
```

Comment: This works but I needed to use `width` and `height` as index instead of `w` and `h`. So if you get an undefined index error you know what to do.

Comment: I am using fpdi 1.6.2. This answer is also useful for the older version of fpdi. Thanks!